# "Lavaan error: sample covariance matrix is not positive-definite" and model not running at all

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I'm trying to run a CFA using `lavaan` `cfa()` function (it is the absolute first time I need to do a CFA in my life, so bear with me). My model however does not run at all, giving the error:

```
Error in lav_samplestats_icov(COV = cov[[g]], ridge = 1e-05, x.idx = x.idx[[g]],  : 
  lavaan ERROR: sample covariance matrix is not positive-definite
```

As it's a huge dataset and due to the nature of the operation, a reproducible example won't really be of help. Instead I'll say what I've got: 230 observations of 38 variables. Initially, some of my variables were ordinal, and the rest were all ratio. I have scaled and centred them using `scale(data, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)`, though.
I've checked and there are: No NAs in the data set, no correlations between variables > 0.9.

My model looks like this:

```
online_questionnaire_cfa_full <- '
duration_experience =~ years_experience

intensity_diversity =~ entropy + family_general + auditory_ratio + visual_ratio + 
hobbies + friends + home + social_activities + neighbours +
texting + emailing +  social_media +
movies + tv + internet_browsing + reading +
shopping + work + school + notes

environm3 =~ environm3 + factor1_3 + factor2_3 

environm2 =~ environm2

environm1 =~ environm1

US =~ factor1 + factor2 + factor3

CS =~ factor4 + factor5 + factor6 +
+ family_other + friends_other + social_media_other  

proficiency =~ auditory_prof_ratio + visual_prof_ratio 

#set as single indicators
years_experience~~0*years_experience
environm2~~0*environm2
environm1~~0*environm1

#correlate error variances
factor4 ~~ factor5
friends_other ~~ social_media_other
friends ~~ social_activities
movies ~~ tv
factor1 ~~ factor2
entropy ~~ home
auditory_ratio ~~ home
emailing ~~ internet_browsing
family_general ~~ visual_ratio
family_general ~~ auditory_prof_ratio
movies ~~ visual_prof_ratio
auditory_ratio ~~ visual_ratio
visual_ratio ~~ reading
texting ~~ visual_prof_ratio
hobbies ~~ social_activities
friends ~~ texting
emailing ~~ healthcare
factor1_3 ~~ factor2_3
factor1_3 ~~ factor1
factor1_3 ~~ factor2`

#fit the model above:
fit_online_questionnaire_cfa_full <- cfa(online_questionnaire_cfa_full, estimator = "MLM", 
                                         data = online_questionnaire_cfa_scaled, std.lv = TRUE)
```

According to what I read from other questions and answers, the problem must be in my data, rather than in the model, because the model wouldn't even run. Could you point me to some possible problems and how to check for these? Any help will be highly valued.

Comment: it is your data (the error message is about your sample covariance matrix).  Correlations near 0.9 are really high, and if there are multiple, you could have multicollinearity in your data, which means the covariance matrix is NPD.  You can verify if the `det()`erminant or smallest `eigen()` value is negative.  You can also start by fitting smaller parts of your model first, then building it up one part at a time (generally good advice anyway).

Comment: Hi @Terrence, thank you for your reply. As I said, I've removed any high correlations, so currently there are none such. My model didn't even run, so there was no object that I could run ```det()``` or ```eigen()``` to. My assumption was that it would run but give a bad fit message if it's too complex. However, I tried your advice with a very simple model, and that runs successfully. In short: it was the complexity of the model.

Comment: I still have a question to the community though: what else would you check before running a model, apart from correlations, missing values, variable types which are not ratio or ordinal?

Comment: Use `det()` or `eigen()` on the covariance matrix of your modeled variables, not a `lavaan-class` object.

Answer (score 1):

Looking back to what I did, it seemed that my model was way too complex. I tried simplifying the error covariance structure, as well as the fixed factors. But what really helped here was having one LESS latent variables. So, the answer was simplifying and collapsing some of the latent variables together (the ones that made theoretical sense to be combined).